# Recursive Database Parse collectDirtyChildren, mutex lock when "pinning" or "saveEventually"

Tags: ios, parsing, recursion, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have users who have a list of conversations.

I have conversations which have a list of messages and users.

I have messages that have a conversation and users (recipient & sender).

This seems to be causing issues when I do "saveEventually" on a message or trying to pin a "message" or any one of these objects due to what is likely a recursive call to the objects pointed by these. Some more information, it seems that after a huge query for up to date conversations, messages, and users, there are 15 threads spun up with "collectDirtyChildren" which seem to begin upon calling "saveEventually" on a message after changing one of its properties (i.e. Status).

Am I using Parse wrong or is this a bug on their end?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I´m facing same issue